# how to list all commands that mongodb server received

Tags: mongodb

The same as the title, Can anybody help me ?

I want to know all the commands mongodb server has performed and the time every command takes . 
How should I do ?

The server is running on windows7 64bit platform.

I think there would be another way which can do this work, it's port monitoring.  but I doubt if I can get all datas of the port mongodb server use.
how to get them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have found the right way to show these commands!
Use mongosniff in the InstallationDirectory/bin, but it's just for Unix or Linux.

[mongosniff](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/mongosniff)

Comment: Thank the people, Thank CCAV and Thank the Party